# not navigating to a new page using routers in vuejs

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, vue-router

//i want to go to another page on the click of a submit button present in the signup form here in the signup form iam sending data to my api so on the click of submit button it moves the data to the api.. but when i click on submit button it saves the data in api but it dos not move to the pGage i want

a) this is my signup html code

```
<div class="signupbutton">
    <button type = "button" class="button-style" @click="signupMethod">Sign Up</button>
       </div>
```

b) this is my signup.js code

```
signupMethod() {
      const signupObj = {
        username: this.enter_details.username,
        email: this.enter_details.email,
        contactNumber: this.enter_details.contactNumber,
        firstName: this.enter_details.firstName,
        lastName:this.enter_details.lastName,
        dob: this.enter_details.dob,
        password: this.enter_details.password,
        countryCode: this.active_language
      }
        this.$store.dispatch('signupUser' , signupObj).then(()=>{
        this.app.$router.push('/mistrecord')
      })
    },
```

c)this is my store's action.js

```
import vue from 'vue';
import vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios'
import {User} from "../../../service/onBoarding";
import {LocalData} from "../../../service/localData";
// import router from "../../../router";

vue.use(vuex);

export default{

  signupUser ({commit}, signUpObj) {

    axios.post('https://dev-api.mysc.io/int/api/v1/user/signup', signUpObj)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        commit('setAuthToken',response.data.result.authToken);
        // this.app.$router.push('/mistrecord')
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })

  },
```

i am not able to navigate to the mistrecord page after successful filling of the signup page. please help me with this

Comment: use this.$router.push('/mistrecord') instead of this.app.$router.push('/mistrecord')

Comment: i have already tried that still it throws an error Cannot read property '$router' of undefined
    at eval (Signupform.js?22e4:269)

Comment: Can you post your router.js file maybe you are doing something wrong in there (didn't import and use router in your app?) or maybe in your main.js you didn't use that router config file?